# no instance of overloaded function "std::make_unique" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, dxgi

I'm doing Info manager for Dxgi and id like to allocate memory for my message but it writes that problem, any other solution

```
        HRESULT hr;
        SIZE_T messageLength;
        // get the size of message i in yte
        GFX_THROW_NOINFO(pDxgiInfoQueue->GetMessage(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, i, nullptr, &messageLength));
        
        auto bytes = std::make_unique<byte[]>(messageLength);
```

And this is the code after that

```
    auto pMessage = reinterpret_cast<DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE*>(bytes.get());
    // get the message and push its description into the vector
    GFX_THROW_NOINFO(pDxgiInfoQueue->GetMessage(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, i, pMessage, &messageLength));
    messages.emplace_back(pMessage->pDescription);
```

Comment: What is the `byte` type you are using? Very similar code using `std::byte` does not generate the error you quote.

Comment: please show a [mre] and the full error message text, your code as is works: https://godbolt.org/z/aess36Wc1. Does your compiler/standard library support c++14?

Comment: Also, give us the *full* error message - that should include the argument type(s) the compiler thinks you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `std::vector` in this case

```
std::vector<byte> bytes(messageLength);
```

then later

```
auto pMessage = reinterpret_cast<DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE*>(bytes.data());
```